# Inspect element on Android without connecting to computer

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, inspect-element, mobile-development

I have a samsung note pro 12.2 and was wondering how I could inspect element on the browser without connecting to a computer? I understand for smaller devices this makes sense to connect to a computer but for a tablet this size or even a 10 inch, the real estate of the screen would allow me to have an efficient workflow. If this is possible, I would be able to design on the go making it so much easier than carrying around my laptop. Perhaps there is a special browser to use?

Comment: install a different browser that provides dev tools?

Comment: I thought about this, but do not know which browser would supply the dev tools

Answer (score 4):

You can try inspect browser applications for android.

[HTML Source Code Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zupilupi.sourcecodeviewer)

[Dago Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oscarperdanakusuma.dagobrowser)

Comment: Dago is cool, thanks. Unfortunately it cannot inspect well all new html5 quircks I use, but at least I could see source and console, which I have been missing on mobile device for long.

Comment: Though, I am not sure if the inspect screen on Dago really is console, at least it does not work like one, still mystery what it does on that screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it before. But it was an rooted device wi custom ROM.

If you use a custom ROM as well you only need to enable ADB over WiFi and everything will work perfectly from there as when it's connected via cable. The vast majority of custom ROMs have this option, and even the ones that don't have the solution isn't that hat. Take a look in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/2295606).

**Update:**

There's also another answer to that very question that explains how to connect via adb via tcp without a rooted phone. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084202/2295606).

Comment: How that solves the need for inspect element type of debug of a web site with android device so that the inspect element action is done from browser/program running on an android device. That is what is meant here.

Comment: I want to inspect web page with android tablet, no use of laptop nor desktop in any phase. Pure observation of my site from android device.

Comment: Sorry but i think it is not possible to inspect directly within the mobile device.

Comment: That is what seems to be the answer, but I added the bounty to find out if someone knows sth we don't come up yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use Google Chrome as your mobile browser, you can add a bookmarklet that allows you to inspect elements directly from your device. Here’s how to do it:

- Open the Chrome browser on your Android device.
- Tap the More Icon in the top right corner of the screen and select “Bookmarks” from the options.
- Find and edit any bookmark from the list.
- In the Name field, type “Inspect Element”.
- In the URL field, paste the following code:

```
javascript:(function () { var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda'; document.body.appendChild(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init() } })();
```

- Save the bookmark.
  Now, when you want to inspect an element on a webpage, simply follow these steps:
- Navigate to the webpage that you want to inspect.
- Tap on the address bar and search for the “Inspect Element” bookmark that you saved earlier.
- Tap on the bookmark to open and use the Chrome Developer Tools.

This method is convenient and easy to use, and it allows you to access the power of Chrome Developer Tools directly on your Android device.

You can read [this article](https://www.mrskt.com/tutorial/inspect-element-on-android-without-computer) for more methods to use Inspect Element feature on Android Phone.